# Glossary or terminology?

Tags: terminology, formality, writing

I write a report that is a degree project in computer science. I put a glossary in the beginning and called it "Terminology and Definitions". Should it be called "glossary" instead?

The actual part looks like this and is right after the abstract and before the table of contents.

> ```
> Terminology and Definitions
> CPU - Central Processing Unit. It is the center of the computer and performs calculations.
> FPGA - Field-Programmable Gate Array. It is a device suitable for hardware prototyping.
> HID - Human Interface Device, e.g. keyboard, touchscreen and mouse.
> MMU - Memory Management Unit. 
> Nios2 - Nios2 is a brand name for a softcore CPU to which one can download a custom CPU design.
> RAM - Random Access Memory. 
> RS-232 - Recommended standard 232 (IEEE) serial interface for UART.
> SDRAM - Synchronous Dynamic Random Access Memory.
> SoC - System on a Chip. It is an integrated circuit that integrates all components of a computer or other electronic systems.
> UART - Universal Asynchronous Receiver / Transmitter. It is a hardware for serial data transmission.
> uClinux - Linux distribution suitable for embedded systems and for FPGA
> ```

.

Comment: A glossary usually comes at the end before the index, so I think you should stick with your original section title.  Or you could mention the acronyms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bearing in mind a glossary is:

> a list of terms in a special subject, field, or area of usage, with accompanying definitions. ([dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/glossary))

the term 'glossary' would be appropriate.  Of course, if there's another glossary in the project, naming it 'Terminology and Definitions' mayn't be wrong.

Obviously adhere to naming conventions already there - if other degree projects in computer science use 'Terminology and Definitions', use that.

Comment: Yes and while this is clearly opinion-based, how could you possibly have got that far without checking the opinion of your university or college or at leat your own course professor, as expressed in whichever guidelines for students they've published?